# Adding string prefix to column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to add a prefix to some of the rows (rows that meet a condition) in a df.
Tried this:

```
work_df['col1'] = 'bla'+work_df['col1'].astype(str) if work_df.col1.str.contains(my_list, regex=True, na=False) else work_df['col1'].astype(str)
```

And got
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

I also tried:

`work_df[work_df.col1.str.contains(ny_list, regex=True, na=False)] = 'bla'+work_df['col1'].astype(str)`

But it didn't work either. What am I missing there?

Answer (score 0):

If need test list is necessary join values by `|` for regex `or` and then pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
 mask = work_df.col1.str.contains('|'.join(my_list), regex=True, na=False)
 s = work_df['col1'].astype(str)
 work_df['col1'] = np.where(mask, 'bla'+ s, s)
```

Or:

```
 work_df['col1'] = s.mask(mask, 'bla'+ s)
```